# Solve first-order ODE with two functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Given two functions $f(t), g(t)$, and denote $f'(t), g'(t)$ as derivative of function $f(t)$ and $g(t)$

If the following equations satisfied
$$
f(t)g'(t) - f'(t)g(t) = A(t),\quad
f(t)^2 + g(t)^2 = B(t)
$$

where $A(t), B(t)$ are some known functions(and sufficient smooth, of course), and initial values for $f(0), g(0)$ are known

How can I solve for $f(t)$ and $g(t)$?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(t)=\rho(t)\cos\phi(t)$ and $g(t)=\rho(t)\sin\phi(t)$. Then, assuming $B(t)> 0$,
$$
f^2+g^2=B \implies \rho^2(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi)=B \implies \rho(t)=\sqrt{B(t)}, \tag{1}
$$
and
\begin{align}
fg'-f'g=A & \implies \rho\cos\phi\,(\rho'\sin\phi+\rho\phi'\cos\phi)-
(\rho'\cos\phi-\rho\phi'\sin\phi)\,\rho\sin\phi=A \\
&\implies\rho^2\phi'\,(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi)=A \\
&\implies B\phi' = A \\
&\implies \phi(t)=\phi(0) + \int_0^t\frac{A(s)}{B(s)}\,ds. \tag{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Use polar coordinates

$$f(t)= B(t)\  \cos(\phi(t)),g(t)= B(t)\  \sin(\phi(t))$$
$$  f(t)\ g'(t) \ - \ g(t)\ f'(t)=A(t) \to  A(t)=B(t)^2$$

With

$$(g/f)'=\frac{ f(t)\ g'(t) \ - \ g(t)\ f'(t)}{f(t)^2} $$

the equation is not a differential equation. Probably an equation for the angle is missing.

Comment: Great idea, but your second line should be  
$$
A = fg'-f'g = 2\phi'\sin\phi\cos\phi = \phi'\sin2\phi = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\sin2\phi
$$
instead, hence finally 
$$
\phi(t) = \frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(C + 2\int A(t) \,\mathrm{d}t\right)
$$
with $C$ a constant of integration.